# C# float to double conversion

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, precision, division

When I perform the following division and cast to float, I get the following value:

```
float fltval = (float)(1183588296 / 65536.0);   //18060.125
```

Performing the same division without cast gives the following double value:

```
double dblval = 1183588296 / 65536.0;   //18060.124145507813
```

Can I find the nearest double value for the given float value?

When I do the following:

```
double nearestdbl = (double)fltval;
```

I get the float value itself and not the nearest double value:

```
//nearestdbl = 18060.125
```

How can I get the more accurate value (18060.124145507813), or a closer value in this case?

I want to be able to store the result in 32 bits (float) and still be able to derive the closer double value by assigning the float value to double variable.

However, the following code gives a more accurate double value:

```
float f = 125.32f;  //125.32
double d = (double)125.32f; //125.31999969482422
```

Why does it find a closer value in the 2nd example and not in the 1st example?

Thanks.

Comment: Write "18060.124145507813" on a piece of paper. Tear the piece of paper such that you remove the "4145507813" part. Write that on another piece of paper, and ask somebody else to restore the 11 decimal places for you (don't give them the original calculation). This is what you're hoping the computer can do for you.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the concept of Rounding, it's not loss-free and not reversible. Also why should 64-bit representation exist, if you could restore it from 32 bits ? That's not conclusive in either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Actually, when I run the code, I got `18060.13` instead of `18060.125`, but I will keep using the latter in my answer.)

> Can I find the nearest double value for the given float value?

You seem to somehow think that the nearest double value for the float `18060.125` is `18060.124145507813`? This is not true. The nearest double value for the float `18060.125` is `18060.125`. This value can be represented by `double` and `float` equally accurately.

> Why does casting `18060.124145507813` to `float` gives `18060.125` then?

Because the nearest `float` to the `double` `18060.124145507813` is `18060.125`. Note that this is the other way round from your understanding. This does not imply that the nearest `double` to the `float` `18060.125`  is `18060.124145507813`, because there are many `double` values in between 2 adjacent `float` values.

It is impossible to go back to "the `double` that you got the `float` from" because when you cast to `float`, you are losing information. You are converting from a 64-bit value to a 32-bit one. That information isn't going back.

> Why does casting 125.32f work then?

Because `float` cannot represent the number 125.32 as accurately as `double` can, so when you cast to double, it tries to approximate it even further. Although it might seem `float` *can* represent `125.32` 100% accurately, that's just an illusion created by the `ToString` method. Always format your floating point numbers with some kind of formatting method, e.g. `string.Format`.

Answer (score 0):

When converting data types, you'll always end up with the type with less precision...
Consider the case when converting int to double

```
int intVal = (int)(10.0/4);
double dblVal = 10.0/4;
//dblVal = 2.5 --- intVal = 2
dblVal = intVal;
//dblVal = 2.00;
```

Bottom Line: 
You can't save memory and save precision at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

When you convert double to float, the double value is rounded to the nearest float value. If the double value is too small or too large to fit into the float type, the result is zero or infinity.
check out this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions